# using ELMAH with visual studio 2003

Tags: elmah, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to use Elmah with Visual Studio 2003, ASP.NET 1.1 (Legacy Application). When i try to add a refernce to Elmah.dll, VS 2003 throws an error which looks like as below:

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required 
to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify 
your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'requirePermission'.

Source Error: 


Line 4:         <section name="exceptionManagement" 
    type="Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSectionHandler,Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement" />
Line 5:          <sectionGroup name="elmah">
Line 6:             <section name="security" requirePermission="false"             type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
Line 7:             <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false"     type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
Line 8:             <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2494; ASP.NET     
Version:1.1.4322.2494
```

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found all the answers for elmah at the following location:

[Elmah Help for .NET 1.1 applications](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/samples/web.config?repo=1x&r=c1d14a9e1626b74a4a606bae8bf9ae829ec641c5)